# How does dependecy injection allow for easier testing - need a java example to grasp the concept?

Tags: java, junit

So I understand what dependecy injection is:

> Instead of having your objects creating a dependency or asking a
>   factory object to make one for them, you pass the needed dependencies
>   in to the constructor or via property setters, and you make it
>   somebody else's problem (an object further up the dependency graph, or
>   a dependency injector that builds the dependency graph). A dependency
>   as I understand here is any other object the current object needs to
>   hold a reference to

great. Now how does this make testing easier? It makes sense that it would but I'm trying to think of an example that would solidify the concept in my head. Can you provide an example of test code becoming easier than it would have been if we hardwired the dependency in the class?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DI or IoC (Inversion of Control) allows you to swap out implementations of an interface.

Comment: Mainly it makes it easier to insert components into a "test harness" where their inputs are controlled by the test driver vs coming from some other (not necessarily fully-tested) component.  Imagine trying to test a transistor while it's in the middle of a computer circuit, vs being able to test it on a workbench with input signals you can control.  Of course, unfortunately there are those will use DI/IoC as an excuse to remove all "smarts" from their components and instead dump that complexity on the "wiring" that hooks everything together, creating an untestable mess.  There's no free lunch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take an example. Let's say that you want to test a Detonator:

```
public class Detonator {
    private Bomb bomb = new AtomicBomb();

    public void pushButton() {
        // do some stuff to test, and at the end
        bomb.explode();
    }
}
```

Now, you have a serious problem, because every time you want to test the detonator, you make the bomb explode, and that is quite costly. So you use dependency injection to solve the problem:

```
public class Detonator {
    private Bomb bomb;

    public Detonator(Bomb bomb) {
        this.bomb = bomb;
    }

    public void pushButton() {
        // do some stuff to test, and at the end
        bomb.explode();
    }
}
```

What does that change for your tests? Everything, because now you can test the detonator this way:

```
Bomb fakeBomb = new WaterBalloonBomb();
Detonator detonator = new Detonator(fakeBomb);
detonator.pushButton();
// test that the fake bomb has exploded
```

Now this is quite an unrealistic scenario. But just replace Detonator by BankingService, and Bomb by MainFrameDatabaseAccessor, and you get the idea: needing a populated mainframe database to test the business logic of a service is very cumbersome, makes the tests hard to write, and slow to execute. By using a mock framework, you can create dynamic implementations of the injected class, and verify assertions of this mock object:

```
MainframeDatabaseAccessor mock = mock(MainFrameDatabaseAccessor.class);
when(mock.findAccount(id1)).thenReturn(sourceAccount);
when(mock.findAccount(id2)).thenReturn(destinationAccount);

BankingService service = new BankingService(mock);
service.transfer(id1, id2, 1000);
// now test that sourceAccount has lost 1000 dollars and destinationAccount has won 1000 dollars

verify(mock).logTransaction(any(Transaction.class));
```

Comment: Wow, what an awesome example! Will never forget this one! lol.. Thank you so much JP Nizet!

Answer (score 0):

Take a periodical batch process writing new facts to the database and doing checks against NOW - 7 DAYS. If you prepare test data, that "NOW" is painful. Initialising that NOW outside the class is one option: The database connection would make an even more regular case for DI.

```
class UpdateBatch { // Class to test
    Date now; // Java 7
    Instant now; // Java 8

    Connection connection;
}
```

Here one could do without DI:

```
class ProductionUpdateBatch extends UüdateBatch { // No  longer tested
    ...
    now = new Date();
    now = Instant.now();
    connection = ...
}
```

but with DI one may keep the actual values declarative, in an XML source or so.
Especially you may define it outside the application, in the application container.

For a more abstract conceptual perspective you might look into *inversion of control*.